# "It is the first time" vs "This is the first time"

Tags: grammar

I have a question related to the usage of "it" and "this". Are they interchangeable in the following context and such contexts?

1- It is the first time I have driven a car.

2- This is the first time I have driven a car.

I searched with [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+the+first+time%2Cthis+is+the+first+time&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=6) and found lots of results for both.

Comment: The examples are the same, perhaps the second is more fluent. But "and such contexts" cannot be answered. Compare "It **was** the first time..." with "This **was** the first time..." Here it would be "**That** was the first time...".

Comment: No. 2 is more used and probably more fluent, but both are fine.

Comment: Using the imperfect/past tense "was" in that situation, and the difference is more easily discernible, but not in the simple present.

Comment: I think it depends entirely on the larger context.  If you're sitting behind the wheel of a car, it would be very natural to say "This is the first time", but saying "It is the first time" sounds weird.  "It" is more general and doesn't necessarily refer to anything present.